# Speaker recognition using Python (recognize who a voice belongs)

Tags: python, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I would like to know if there is a library or tool for python that allows me to retrieve any identification for a recorded voice based on prior data.

For example:

```
import voice_recorder
import speaker_recognition


voices = ['obama.wav','trump.wav','biden.wav']

sr = speaker_recognition.load(voices)


recorded_voice = voice_recorder.record()
speaker_id = sr.identify(recorded_voice)

#"The speaker is likely ____ (obama/trump/biden)"
print("The speaker is likely "+voices[speaker_id].split('.')[0])
```

Comment: You'd probably need to train your own machine learning model

Comment: not mine but try: https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu

Comment: @FaridFakhry Very interesting project, but unfortunately according to the description:
"Note: for voice recognition, Dejavu is not the right tool! Dejavu excels at recognition of exact signals with reasonable amounts of noise."

Comment: what about this? https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/ 
there are tools it's just a matter of research